# Enable multithreaded BLAS/LAPACK in NumPy @ macOS BigSur 12.1

Tags: macos, command-line, python, macports, open-source

I would like to enable a multithreaded BLAS/LAPACK backend for Python's (v3.9.9) NumPy on my macOS BigSur (v12.1). When I run my NumPy code, I see in `htop`, that only one `python` process is running and the core utilisation is 20–25%. I remember in the past, stock MacPorts NumPy installation would use [Apple’s Accelerate library](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate) including the multithreaded BLAS and LAPACK. As I understand this is no longer the case.

I run Python code using a virtual environment located under

```
/opt/venv/zipfstime/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core
```

When I change there and issue

```
otool -L _multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so

_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so:
@loader_path/../.dylibs/libopenblas.0.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1281.100.1)
```

i.e. NumPy relies on OpenBLAS. Command `port variants openblas` returns

```
OpenBLAS has the variants:
  g95: Build using the g95 Fortran compiler
    * conflicts with gcc10 gcc11 gcc8 gcc9 gccdevel
  gcc10: Build using the MacPorts gcc 10 compiler
    * conflicts with g95 g95 gcc11 gcc8 gcc9 gccdevel
[+]gcc11: Build using the MacPorts gcc 11 compiler
    * conflicts with g95 g95 gcc10 gcc8 gcc9 gccdevel
  gcc8: Build using the MacPorts gcc 8 compiler
    * conflicts with g95 g95 gcc10 gcc11 gcc9 gccdevel
  gcc9: Build using the MacPorts gcc 9 compiler
    * conflicts with g95 g95 gcc10 gcc11 gcc8 gccdevel
  gccdevel: Build using the MacPorts gcc devel compiler
    * conflicts with g95 g95 gcc10 gcc11 gcc8 gcc9
[+]lapack: Add Lapack/CLapack support to the library
  native: Force compilation on machine to get fully optimized library
  universal: Build for multiple architectures
```

I tried installing the “native” variant of OpenBLAS port with `sudo port install openblas +native` and setting the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS=8`, but I didn’t see any improvement when running my Python code. I would welcome your help and guidance on this subject.

Comment: I think you need to ask on macports mailing lists. I suspect that you need to install a multi processor C compiler, this is from browsing the mailing lists but I don't actually use these. The user list is at https://lists.macports.org/mailman/listinfo/macports-users